# ReferenceError: require is not defined in electron renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm currently working on an electron application, I'm trying to use node in the renderer, but whenever I try to use `require`, it throws `ReferenceError: require is not defined`, I have `nodeIntegration` set to `true` and I'm not entirely sure what I could do to make it work.
I have tried setting `contextIsolation` to `false` but that breaks jQuery.

This is what I'm trying to reference in the js file:

```
const electron = require('electron');
```

Which just results in `ReferenceError: require is not defined` as I said above.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! We can't help you much without code. :).

Comment: I edited it, hope it should be enough.

Comment: You should include your settings as well, IE where you set `nodeIntegration` to true.

Comment: Set contextIsolation to false and then add this line in your HTML file as the first script that's called. Jquery should work now. ```<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>```